# Basic easy_install question on python 2.6

Tags: python, imagemagick, easy-install

I'm trying to install a python api for controlling imagemagick ([this](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/pythonmagickwand)) and followed the instructions.

I imported easy_install:

```
import easy_install
```

and then input the line:

```
easy_install http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/pythonmagickwand/trunk
```

However I got the error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and 'http' was highlighted. I'm wondering what causes the error - this is on Windows XP.

Comment: What caused you to think that `import easy_install` was part of the process?

Comment: I presumed that it was within the python shell, hence needed to be imported. I now realize I run it from the dos command line.

When I run it I get the error: error: Couldn't find a setup script in c:\windows\temp\easy_install-ehhshj\trunk

(I'm not sure if it is ok to ask this question here or whether this be something separate)

Comment: @womble: The `easy_install` error is a separate question.   Close this one (or accept one of the answers) and open a new question with your easy_install question.  You haven't installed easy_install correctly, so be prepared to describe how you did install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check
http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#using-easy-install
for a good reference.

also, easy_install is run from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

`easy_install` is a shell command, run at the shell.

It's not a python command; it's not run from within Python.

Answer (score 1):

I believe easy_install is a script that should be run from the command line

Answer (score 0):

Typical easy_install usage would be more like "easy_install imagemagick", a package name rather than a pointer to an svn repository. It looks like you can install from [svn via easy_install](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/664977-easy_install-svn) with the -i flag. Long-term, I'd suggest looking at [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip): it does everything easy_install does, but with a lot more flexibility and without creating eggs for everything (which makes it easier to edit and modify by hand when you need to patch something).